# Rails clientsidevalidations conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, client-side-validation

Well, there are two divs and as you see from the code I dynamically make them visible once the page loaded and select_tag value changed. As you see from the model the helpers of both divs get validated on server side by conditions.  I want to make the same thing on client side. So tried forcing validation just for presence, tried to use f.object, enabled and disabled the validations. No luck. 
Once the form gets loaded conditons on server side are loaded so first div works by loading "Personal" but when I load the other div (by js); since the conditons are loaded for "personal" business type, conditons for "company" doesn't work and clientside validations don't get fired. Partials make it complicated and I can't reload the page since there are pictures selected without cache and live map data is there.

Is there anything I don't know about clientsidevalidations that you may recommend me to sort this out?

**model**

```
 validates :tax_number, length: { is: 10}, presence: true, uniqueness: true,  :if => :company? 
  validates :tax_office, presence: true, :if => :company? 
  validates :tax_business_name, presence: true, :if => :company? 
  validates :tax_pin, length: { is: 11 }, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :if => :personal? 
  validates :tax_fullname, presence: true, :if => :personal? 

  def personal?
    if business_type == 1 || business_type == 0
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
  end

  def company? 
    if business_type == 2 || business_type == 3
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
  end
```

**view**

```
%fieldset
  = f.select :business_type, options_for_select(business_type_options,@provider.business_type),{},:style => "width:150px"
  #taxpersonal
    = f.text_field :tax_fullname, :validate => { :presence => true }, :class=>"input-xlarge"
    = f.text_field :tax_pin, :validate => { :presence => true }, :class=>"input-medium {mask:'99999999999'}", :alt=> "99999999999" 
    .control-group{id:"tax_helper"}
      .controls
        %p.help-block{style:"margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: -10px;"} 
          %small
            = t('tax_info')
  #taxbusiness
    = f.text_field :tax_business_name, :validate => { :presence => f.object.business_type != 0 ? true : false }, :class=>"input-xxlarge"
    = f.text_field :tax_office,:validate => { :presence => true }, :class=>"input-large"
    = f.text_field :tax_number, :validate => { :presence => true }, :class=>"input-medium {mask:'9999999999'}", :alt=> "9999999999" 
    .control-group
      .controls
        %p.help-block{style:"margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: -10px;"} 
          %small
            = t('tax_info')
```

**coffee**

```
  $("#provider_business_type").bind "change", -> 
    if $(this).val() is "0" or $(this).val() is "1"
      $("#taxpersonal").show()
      $("#taxbusiness").hide()
      $('#provider_tax_number').disableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_business_name').disableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_business_office').disableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_pin').enableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_fullname').enableClientSideValidations()
    else 
      $("#taxpersonal").hide()
      $("#taxbusiness").show()
      $('#provider_tax_number').enableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_business_name').enableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_business_office').enableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_pin').disableClientSideValidations()
      $('#provider_tax_fullname').disableClientSideValidations()
  $('#provider_business_type').trigger "change"
```

[image]

[image]